# Why does this do-while-loop only write to the arrays every other loop?

Tags: c++

The purpose of this do while loop is to enter coordinates(or points) into two arrays: points_x[] and points_y[]. The loop is to stop when the user enters a non integer input. For some reason only every other cin actually writes to the arrays. Does anyone know why?

```
cout << "Enter a list of points(x y): ";
do
{
    cin >> points_x[v];
    cout << points_x[v];
    cin >> points_y[v];
    cout << points_x[v];
    howMany++;
    v++;
} while (cin >> points_x[v] && cin >> points_y[v]);
```

Comment: Because you read twice each loop but only increment once.  (The read in the condition of the `while` consumes data.)

Comment: What are your observations which make you think that "only every other cin actually writes to the arrays"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think there are four reads in each loop. See the loop condition.

Comment: @Yunnosch, there are a total of 4.  2 to points_x[v] and 2 to points_y[v].

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, it would help if you provided the input you give and the observations you make, instead of your (possibly flawed!) interpretations. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It probably also doesn't help when checking the correctness of the output that your `cout` statements are both printing the same value from `points_x` rather than the second one printing from `points_y` as I suspect is intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are reading twice (once for each coordinate, x and y)

```
cin >> points_x[v];
cout << points_x[v];
cin >> points_y[v];
cout << points_x[v];
```

I assume that you mean this to be "one cin".

Then you increase the index you use while writing the results to the array.

```
v++;
```

Then you read again once into each coordinate, while evaluating the loop condition:

```
while (cin >> points_x[v] && cin >> points_y[v])
```

I assume that you mean that to be the second "cin".

The readings during the condition (i.e. the second "cin") write already to the next index,
but the reading inside the body then writes to that same index again (overwriting the values from the condition read).

So in the end you enter each xy twice, once ignored during the condition, once "surviving" inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

As the input can be multiple digits, prefer to enter as string, check each digit to be numbers and assign after converting to integer. See snippet:

```
bool IsAlpha(string s) {    
    for (const auto& c : s)
        if (isalpha(c)) return true;
    return false;
}

void main()

{     
    string str;
    cout << "Enter a list of points(x y):";

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "\n Enter X ";
        cin >> str;
        if (IsAlpha(str)) break;
        points_x[v] = std::stoi(str);
        cout << "  " << points_x[v] ;

        cout << "\n Enter Y ";
        cin >> str;
        if (IsAlpha(str)) break;
        points_y[v] = std::stoi(str);
        cout << points_y[v] << "  ";

        howMany++; 
        v++;
    };

}
```